# Transcoding HTTP/JSON to gRPC in .NetCore

Tags: c#, .net-core, grpc

I recently found out that there is the possibility of "Transcoding" the gRPC server so that it can receive HTTP/JSON requests as well as gRPC requests. I believe this will allow users to use the normal NetCore HTTP Client to send a request to a gRPC server (using protobuf of course). I have seen this implementation in other languages (mainly Go), but I have not been able to see anything on how this can be done in.NetCore and C#. Do you have any idea how this can be achieved?

This is the official Goggle documentation on the subject: https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/grpc/transcoding

Thank You Very Much

Comment: I wonder if this might be better suited to an issue here: https://github.com/grpc/grpc-dotnet or https://github.com/grpc/grpc

Answer (score 3):

I think the best way is to use the `google api` HTTP options and configure Envoy proxy to do the transcoding.

I got this working previously based on info on  [Christophe Hesters'](https://blog.jdriven.com/2018/11/transcoding-grpc-to-http-json-using-envoy/) blog.

However, deployment is a bit fiddly (especially on Windows, which is what I develop on).

The first method I used for debugging was:

- Run WSL Ubuntu / WSL 2 Ubuntu / Ubuntu VM
- Install docker in Linux
- Run `envoyproxy/envoy`
- Run your gRPC service manually on the host

You can use docker (desktop if on Windows) / docker-compose to make a more portable setup where Envoy and your service both run as containers.

Prompted by your question, I just discovered [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Grpc.HttpApi](https://github.com/aspnet/AspLabs/tree/master/src/GrpcHttpApi).
Its only a WIP preview for now, but looks to be a much easier option to get started with.

Comment: I have a particular use case to make the gRPC services compatible with systems that supports HTTP calls in a Kubernetes Cluster. How to access the JSON Transcoded API in the scenario where the dotnet gRPC services are accessed over HTTP?

I get 400 Bad Request for calls to http endpoint, https endpoint works fine.

`An HTTP/1.x request was sent to an HTTP/2 only endpoint.`

Comment: @vCillusion that error is specific to the dotnet transcoding solution, which is no longer WIP and will ship in .net 7.0. Could you create a new question with that background information?

Answer (score 1):

After 2 years, I recently saw that Microsoft have included this feature in their gRPC implementation in NetCore. Here you can find the detailed explanation and how to include this functionality in your gRPC server in .Net

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-grpc-json-transcoding-for-dotnet/